# Jenkins console on mail

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have to show console output directly on the mail triggered from Jenkins through Email-ext plugin. or is it possible to show screen of parsed console on mail

Answer (score 4):

Put `${BUILD_LOG}` in the field of Default Content to show the full log or use `${BUILD_LOG,maxLines=N}` to show the final N lines only. N is an integer.